# Sync existing project with remote server via SFTP , Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ubuntu, sftp

i have imported a bitbucket project via **GIT** , so currenlty i have a working code .

Now i have put my imported code to my development server .
So now i want to sync my local code and code in development server via **SFTP** .
So the local project should be sync with bitbucket using **GIT** and sync with dev server using **SFTP** .

i checked for eclipse plugins , like jcraft , SFTP , Remote System Explorer , but i think they first import the project from the remote location .

But i want to sync existing project with remote server   .

Can that be done using these plugins , or are their any other solutions .Thank you.

Comment: Just wondering: Why using SFTP if you could create a Git repo there too and simply push the changes there?

Comment: @rlegendi simple reason , my boss does not like it :P

Comment: Oh ok... Then what I'd suggest: write a small script that does the sftp magic and link it as an [external tool](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-exttools-running.htm) within Eclipse. I believe it is more convenient than doing the copy every time by hand.